# parse through json correctly

Tags: jquery, json, parsing, jsonp

I have this json file:

```
{
"categories": [
    {
        "producerName": "Canon",
        "productName": [
            {
                "kamera": "EOS 5D",
                "link": "/unterwassergehaeuse-fuer/canon-eos-5d/",
                "kamera": "EOS 5D Mark II",
                "link": "/unterwassergehaeuse-fuer/canon-eos-5d/",
                "kamera": "EOS 5D Mark III",
                "link": "/unterwassergehaeuse-fuer/canon-eos-5d/",
                "productObj": [
                    {
                        "objektiv": "Canon EF 15mm f/2.8 Fisheye",
                        "link": "/uw-ports-fuer/vollformat/canon-ef-8-15mm-f-4l-fisheye-usm/"
                    },
                    {
                        "objektiv": "Canon EF 8-15mm f/4L Fisheye USM",
                        "link": "/uw-ports-fuer/vollformat/canon-ef-8-15mm-f-4l-fisheye-usm/"
                    },
                    {
                        "objektiv": "Canon EF 14mm f/2.8L USM",
                        "link": "/uw-ports-fuer/vollformat/canon-ef-8-15mm-f-4l-fisheye-usm/"
                    },
                    {
                        "objektiv": "Canon 24mm f/1.4 L USM",
                        "link": "/uw-ports-fuer/vollformat/canon-ef-8-15mm-f-4l-fisheye-usm/"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "kamera": "EOS 7D",
                "link": "/uw-ports-fuer/vollformat/canon-ef-8-15mm-f-4l-fisheye-usm/",
                "productObj": [
                    {
                        "objektiv": "Canon EF 15mm f/2.8 Fisheye",
                        "link": "/uw-ports-fuer/vollformat/canon-ef-8-15mm-f-4l-fisheye-usm/"
                    },
                    {
                        "objektiv": "Canon EF 8-15mm f/4L Fisheye USM",
                        "link": "/uw-ports-fuer/vollformat/canon-ef-8-15mm-f-4l-fisheye-usm/"
                    },
                    {
                        "objektiv": "Canon EF 14mm f/2.8L USM",
                        "link": "/uw-ports-fuer/vollformat/canon-ef-8-15mm-f-4l-fisheye-usm/"
                    },
                    {
                        "objektiv": "Canon 24mm f/1.4 L USM",
                        "link": "/uw-ports-fuer/vollformat/canon-ef-8-15mm-f-4l-fisheye-usm/"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "producerName": "Nikon",
        "productName": [
            {
                "kamera": "D800",
                "link": "/uw-ports-fuer/vollformat/canon-ef-8-15mm-f-4l-fisheye-usm/",
                "productObj": [
                    {
                        "objektiv": "Canon EF 15mm f/2.8 Fisheye",
                        "link": "/uw-ports-fuer/vollformat/canon-ef-8-15mm-f-4l-fisheye-usm/"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "producerName": "Olympus",
        "productName": [
            {
                "kamera": "OM-D EM-5",
                "link": "/uw-ports-fuer/vollformat/canon-ef-8-15mm-f-4l-fisheye-usm/",
                "productObj": [
                    {
                        "objektiv": "Canon EF 15mm f/2.8 Fisheye",
                        "link": "/uw-ports-fuer/vollformat/canon-ef-8-15mm-f-4l-fisheye-usm/"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

I parse through this via jQuery with json callback which is working well.

The only problem is that I want to get all "kamera" with "link" connected to "productObj" but I always get only the last string.

Hope you can help me.

The jQuery part:

```
$('#model').on("change", function() {
    var indx = $("#cat").find(".selectBox-label").attr("id");
    //console.log(indx);
    var item = '<option id="std">2. Kamera auswählen:</option>';
    for (n=0; n < menu[indx].productName.length; n++){
        item += '<option id="'+[n]+'">' + menu[indx].productName[n].kamera + '</option>';
    }
    $('#camera').html(item);
    $('#camera').selectBox('refresh');
    $('#camera').selectBox('enable');
    $.cookie('m', menu[indx].producerName);
    $.removeCookie('k');
    $.removeCookie('o');


    //second onChange
    $('#camera').on("change", function() {

        var indy = $("#items").find(".selectBox-label").attr("id");
        var goRef = menu[indx].productName[indy].link;

        if(goRef) {

            $.cookie('k', menu[indx].productName[indy].kamera);
            if($(".leftfinder").length > 0) {
                $(".gofind").css({'background': 'url(leftgofind.png)', 'cursor':'pointer'});
            }else {
                $(".gofind").css({'background': 'url(gofindbt.png)', 'cursor':'pointer'});
            }

            $(".gofind").on("click", function() {
                window.location.href = "url"+goRef;
            });
        }
});
```

Comment: Post the relevant JS code that you use for parsing this object.

Comment: question edited adding the code

Comment: very bad JSON structure :/

Answer (score 0):

With this code, your properties are overwritten:

```
var obj = { "kamera": "EOS 5D",
    "link": "/unterwassergehaeuse-fuer/canon-eos-5d/",
    "kamera": "EOS 5D Mark II",
    "link": "/unterwassergehaeuse-fuer/canon-eos-5d/",
    "kamera": "EOS 5D Mark III",
    "link": "/unterwassergehaeuse-fuer/canon-eos-5d/"
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
var obj =   {  "kamera": "EOS 5D Mark III",
    "link": "/unterwassergehaeuse-fuer/canon-eos-5d/"}
```

That's the reason why you get only the last string. You cannot define an object with multiple properties with the same name

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this structure:

```
 { 
   "kamera": "EOS 5D",
   "link": "/unterwassergehaeuse-fuer/canon-eos-5d/",
   "kamera": "EOS 5D Mark II",
   "link": "/unterwassergehaeuse-fuer/canon-eos-5d/",
   "kamera": "EOS 5D Mark III",
   "link": "/unterwassergehaeuse-fuer/canon-eos-5d/"
 }
```

why not have:

```
[
   {
      "kamera": "EOS 5D",
      "link": "/unterwassergehaeuse-fuer/canon-eos-5d/"
   },
   {
      "kamera": "EOS 5D Mark II",
      "link": "/unterwassergehaeuse-fuer/canon-eos-5d/"
   },
   {
      "kamera": "EOS 5D Mark III",
      "link": "/unterwassergehaeuse-fuer/canon-eos-5d/"
   }
]
```

ie an array of objects. Then you can just iterate over it.

Answer (score 0):

It's not good JSON structure, you overwrite your values, because you use same keys

Anyway here is how to parse:

```
$.each(json.categories, function(key, val) {
    $.each(val.productName, function(key, val) {
        console.log("kamera: " + val.kamera + " | link:" + val.link);
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/ugYLb/)